# Trying to get value from $this-> through another variable value in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables

Alright,so I'm trying to get the value from `$this->lang->line('test');`

I got another variable called `$try`, which contains the value `$this->lang->line('test');`.

I can successfully make it print out the name `$this->lang->line('test');`, but I can't get it to print out the value of that variable.

When trying with `eval()`, or `$$`, I just get a `undefined variable` error.
But I've double-checked, by doing `echo $this->lang->line('test');` with success.

So, do anyone know how this could be solved?

Comment: You will need to use eval, what does `eval("echo $try;");` do?

Comment: I tried using eval earlier, but it just gives me a NULL value.

Comment: Does `$this` and `$this->lang->line` exist from where you are trying to call it?

Comment: As mentioned above, I've printed out `echo $this->lang->line('test');` 
with success.

Comment: What did it look like when you tried eval?  I mean what was the code you used when you called eval?

Comment: Well, when I'm doing a `eval("echo $try");`, I do get the value, but it seems not to be outprinted correctly, because my other function doesn't pick it up.
I guess it has something to do with that eval prints out the value, the function itself?
So when I'm trying to do a `$newVar = eval("echo $test");`, things goes wrong? :/

Comment: See my new answer based on the last comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer based on your comments.

When you call `eval`, it evaluates the string given as PHP code.  Since you call `$newVar = eval("echo $test;");`, the value is `echo`ed to standard output.

As the [manual](http://php.net/eval) states about the return value of `eval`,

> **eval()** returns `NULL` unless ***return*** is called in the evaluated code, in
>   which case the value passed to ***return*** is returned. If there is a parse
>   error in the evaluated code, **eval()** returns `FALSE` and execution of the
>   following code continues normally.

If you want to capture the value from the `eval`ed string rather than echo it, then replace `echo` with `return`.

Example:

```
$newVar = eval("return $test;");
echo $newVar;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know how eval(); works exactly, but now after your explanation, it all worked out.

Comment: Cool glad to help and hear that you got it working now.  `php.net/function_name` is a good place to start looking.  The manual is really helpful with its explanations and examples.